# Match two words that is on the same line

Tags: text-processing, sed, grep

The command that I have prints out two of the lines whenever **FW_6.0.0** is found, below is the code:

```
grep -oP 'FW_6.0.0, (.*)$' file
```

Below is the output, both has the same value of **FW_6.0.0**

```
FW_6.0.0, SUCCESS
FW_6.0.0, OK
```

I would like to match two words, that is **FW_6.0.0** and **SUCCESS** that can be found on the same line so that it prints this out:

`FW_6.0.0, SUCCESS` and eliminates `FW_6.0.0, OK`

Comment: Is the order matter?

Comment: Yes FW_6.0.0 should come first.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try using double quotes `""`:

```
grep -oP "FW_6.0.0, SUCCESS" file
```

OR (Because it is a fixed string, not a pattern):

```
grep -oF "FW_6.0.0, SUCCESS" file
```

from grep man page:

```
-F, --fixed-strings
          Interpret  PATTERN  as  a  list  of  fixed strings, separated by
          newlines, any of which is to be matched.  (-F  is  specified  by
          POSIX.)
-P, --perl-regexp
          Interpret PATTERN as a Perl regular expression.  This is  highly
          experimental and grep -P may warn of unimplemented features.
```

Comment: I don't see the regex there, let alone the PCRE. So why `grep -P` instead of `grep -F`?

Comment: @HaukeLaging, updated

Answer (score 5):

If you want to use `awk`:

```
awk '/FW_6\.0\.0/ && /SUCCESS/' file
```

Comment: you have to escape the dots, otherwise it matches `FW_6f0f0` also.

Answer (score 4):

Try:

```
grep -o 'FW_6.0.0.*SUCCESS' file
```

We don't need `-P` option here.

Answer (score 2):

Through sed,

```
$ sed -n '/FW_6\.0\.0.*SUCCESS/p' file
FW_6.0.0, SUCCESS
```