# How can I find all lines containing two specified words, case-insensitively?

Tags: text-processing, awk, grep, case-sensitivity

I need to check if two (specified) words exist on any line in a text file. There are no limits for the characters of the words. For example:

I want to find lines of a text file that contain the two words “cat” and “elephant” together (i.e., on the same line;
not necessarily side-by-side):

```
Cat is smaller than elephant
Elephant is larger than cat
Cats are cute!
Elephants are very strong
Cat and elephants live in different environments
cats are friendly
```

In the previous examples, how can I find the lines containing both words?

```
Cat is smaller than elephant
Elephant is larger than cat
Cat and elephants live in different environments
```

I tried grep and awk with no hope. The problem is there are words that have upper and lower case, so how can I match for both words regardless of their letter status!?

Comment: Try with `grep` again, but use `grep -i`. This makes its matching disregard the case of the letters.  Also, please show what you've tried so that other's make comment and give suggestions for improvement.  For example, does your command distinguish that "catnip" is _not_ the word "cat"?

Comment: Related: [grep with logic operators](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/177513/grep-with-logic-operators)

Comment: [How to run grep with multiple AND patterns?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/55359/44425), [How to use grep to match multiple strings in the same line?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4487328/995714), [grep for 2 words existing on the same line](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6480687/995714), [Grep searching two words in a line](https://askubuntu.com/q/590384/253474)

Comment: or [Match two words that are on the same line](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/140661/22142)

Comment: A proposed edit wants to add the [case-sensitivity] tag which seems ok, and mention it in the title. But is also proposes removing the [grep] tag for no reason, which is bad.  I don't have enough rep on this site to approve-and-edit or reject-and-edit.  (@Kusalananda perhaps you'd care to take a look.)

Comment: @PeterCordes Sorted. Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

With `grep`

```
grep -i "cat" file | grep -i "elephant"

Cat is smaller than elephant
Elephant is larger than cat
Cat and elephants live in different environment
```

The flag in `grep` is to ignore case (upper/lower)

```
 -i, --ignore-case         ignore case distinctions
```

or `awk`

```
awk 'BEGIN{IGNORECASE=1} /cat/&&/elephant/{print $0}' file
```

*@glenn jackman* suggested that `awk` statement can be run as follows:

```
awk '/cat/&&/elephant/' IGNORECASE=1 file
```

Comment: The `{print $0}` block is optional since it is the default action.

Comment: I would leave your answer as it is. FYI the awk command can be "golfed" to `awk '/cat/&&/elephant/' IGNORECASE=1 file` -- also I believe IGNORECASE is specific to GNU awk

Comment: @glenn: IGNORECASE is indeed GNU; `tolower($0)~/cat/` (or similarly with `toupper`) is standard, but may give undesired results in some (non-English) locales with accented letters and especially Turkish with its dotted and dotless i's.

Answer (score 6):

```
$ grep -Fiw cat <file | grep -Fiw elephant
Cat is smaller than elephant
Elephant is larger than cat
```

We first extract all lines from the file `file` that contains the word `cat` and then narrow down those lines to the ones that contains the word `elephant`.

This is done using `grep -F -i -w` where

- `-F` makes `grep` treat the pattern as a fixed string, not as a regular expression,
- `-i` makes `grep` do case-insensitive matching, and
- `-w` makes `grep` match complete words only.

The `-w` option is an extension of [the POSIX standard for `grep`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/utilities/grep.html), but is implemented by most common `grep` implementations. It basically disallows matches of the given patten when the matching string is part of a longer word.

Note that I'm not matching the line

```
Cat and elephants live in different environment
```

This is due to the final `s` in `elephants`.  I would also not match the line

```
elephantiasis is catastrophic
```

for the same reason.

Would you want to allow for a plural `s` at the end of words, use

```
$ grep -Eiw 'cats?' <file | grep -Eiw 'elephants?'
Cat is smaller than elephant
Elephant is larger than cat
Cat and elephants live in different environment
```

Here, we use an (extended) regular expression instead of a fixed string in both invocations of `grep`.  The expressions will match an optional `s` at the end of the two words. Now we match `cat` and `cats` (case-insensitively), but would not match `catnip`, `catsup`, or `scat`.

Answer (score 3):

with GNU sed:

```
sed -n '/cat/I {/elephant/I p}' file
```

or perl

```
perl -ne 'print if /cat/i and /elephant/i' file
```

or a single grep

```
grep -i -e 'cat.*elephant' -e 'elephant.*cat' file
```

Comment: how do I insert a text at the end of found line using sed?

Answer (score 3):

You can do it in non-GNU `awk`
by using the “poor man’s” trick to get case insensitivity:

```
awk  '/[Cc][Aa][Tt]/ && /[Ee][Ll][Ee][Pp][Hh][Aa][Nn][Tt]/'  file
```

where, just as `[aeiou]` matches any one of `a`, `e`, `i`, `o` or `u`, 
`[Ee]` matches either `E` or `e` — that is, a case-insensitive match for “e”.

Note that this approach (like ***all*** the other answers posted here so far)
will match the line

```
There are many ways to catch an elephant.
```

because the word “**cat**ch” contains the string “cat”. 
If you want to avoid this, try

```
awk  '/(^|\W)[Cc][Aa][Tt](\W|$)/ && /(^|\W)[Ee][Ll][Ee][Pp][Hh][Aa][Nn][Tt](\W|$)/'  file
```

where you constrain each word
to be preceded by a non-word character (or the beginning of the line)
and followed by a non-word character (or the end of the line) —
`\W` matches a non-word character (i.e., a space (or tab)
or other non-alphanumeric ***** character).

(I’m not sure whether this is POSIX-compliant.)

Note that this will now ***not*** match

```
Cat and elephants live in different environments
```

because the word “elephants” is not the same as the word “elephant”.
__________________________
***** In this context, underscore (the “_” character) counts as a letter.