# Search two or more strings in a file

Tags: grep

I've SQL files on my database server which is a unix box. I am trying to find out what are the *.sql files which use a particular column of  a table. For eg the content of `my_dir/SALES_TERRITORY.sql` is

```
Select segment1,segment2
from HZ_CUST_SITE_USES_ALL
where territory_id = :p_territory_id;
```

So , my requirement is when I run my command I should get all the files which have the combination of 'HZ_CUST_SITE_USES_ALL' and 'territory_id'.

I did below by searching the internet but I am not getting the desired output.

```
grep -i "HZ_CUST_SITE_USES_ALL\|TERRITORY_ID" *
```

My expectation is that the above command will give me a result like this

```
grep -i "HZ_CUST_SITE_USES_ALL\|TERRITORY_ID" my_dir/*

SALES_TERRITORY.sql
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Regards,

Comment: This sounds like https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/475908/how-can-i-find-all-lines-containing-two-specified-words --> https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/55359/how-to-run-grep-with-multiple-and-patterns

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use grep as below to list only filenames ( **-l** ): ( "**-maxdepth 0**" is to check on only under my_dir and it will not check sub directories in it.If you want sub-directories also to be checked , just remove that )

If your filenames having spaces in that you can use as below:

```
find ./* -maxdepth 0 -type f -exec grep -qi "HZ_CUST_SITE_USES_ALL" {} \; -and -exec grep -li "TERRITORY_ID" {} \;
```

**Edited for Solaris:**

```
find ./* -prune -type f -exec /usr/xpg4/bin/grep -qi "HZ_CUST_SITE_USES_ALL" {} \; -a -exec /usr/xpg4/bin/grep -li "TERRITORY_ID" {} \;
```

If you are sure that you do NOT have any spaces in between filenames , you can use simple for loop as below :

```
for file in $(find my_dir/* -maxdepth 0 -type f)
do
  grep -qi "HZ_CUST_SITE_USES_ALL" "$file" && grep -il "TERRITORY_ID" "$file";
done
```

Comment: It'd be better, generally speaking, to use `find ... -exec grep 1 ... -exec grep 2` as the command substitution will split any filenames on IFS (space, tab, newline).

Comment: @JeffSchaller : Yeah right !!! Updated again . Thanks Jeff for pointing me things :)

Comment: thanks for your response , but this is giving me file names which has either HZ_CUST_SITE_USES_ALL or territory_id as string. I tested it by creating a  test_file.txt . The file contains text <br/>

'HZ_CUST_SITE_USES_ALL'<br/>
't_ID'<br/>

still this command is printing test_file.txt when actually it should not print it as the "territory_id" string is not present in the file.

Comment: @Praveen : I tested it in that scenario also , it worked rightly for me. Have you used "-q" option in grep as i mentioned in the first grep command ?

Comment: if i use the first command directly i get  <br/>
find: bad option -and  <br/>

so changed it to  && and ran it i get error <br/>

grep: illegal option -- q  <br/>
Usage: grep -hblcnsviw pattern file . . .  <br/>

Comment: Ohh Which Linux Flavor you are using , then remove "-and" , try with "-a" instead of -and and it its still saying -a is bad option , then just give space between each -exec and try ...

Comment: Latest Linux distros have GNU find , which works perfectly for me here...

Comment: @StalinVigneshKumar please find below version
>uname -v
Generic_150400-50
>uname -r
5.10

Comment: Ahhh , its SOLARIS Server ...

Comment: find my_dir/* -type f -exec grep -qi "HZ_CUST_SITE_USES_ALL" {} \; -a -exec grep -li "TERRITORY_ID" {} \;


this command give me error

grep: illegal option -- q
Usage: grep -hblcnsviw pattern file . . .

Comment: 5 mins...checking for solaris find and grep...pls

Comment: @StalinVigneshKumar thanks

Comment: @Praveen : Can you try the command which i mentioned above in the answer for Solaris ...I do not have Solaris machine now ..you have to test it ...:(

Comment: thank you so much !! @StalinVigneshKumar , it worked like a charm ! thanks again for all your help !!

Comment: @Praveen : Pleasure ... thanks ...Have a great day !!!

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with below:

```
grep -w "HZ_CUST_SITE_USES_ALL|TERRITORY_ID" file.txt
```

Comment: The | says "match either" while the OP wants to match *both*

Comment: this command doesn't print anything on the screen

Answer (score 0):

if your grep supports PCRE extension, you can use:

```
grep -iP '(?s)(?=.*HZ_CUST_SITE_USES_ALL)(?=.*territory_id)' infile
```